# Reading realtime audio data into numpy array

Tags: python, audio

how can I read real-time audio into numpy array and use matplotlib to plot ?

Right Now I am recording audio on an `wav` file then using `scikits.audiolab.wavread` to read it into an array. 
Is there a way I could do this directly in realtime?

Answer (score 33):

You can use [`PyAudio`](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) to record audio and use [`np.frombuffer`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) to convert it into a numpy array.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

CHUNKSIZE = 1024 # fixed chunk size

# initialize portaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=44100, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNKSIZE)

# do this as long as you want fresh samples
data = stream.read(CHUNKSIZE)
numpydata = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)

# plot data
plt.plot(numpydata)
plt.show()

# close stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

If you want to record stereo instead of mono, you have to set `channels` to `2`. Then you get an array with interleaved channels. You can reshape it like this:

```
frame = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=numpy.int16)       # interleaved channels
frame = np.stack((frame[::2], frame[1::2]), axis=0)  # channels on separate axes
```

Comment: Thanks. I've used `alsaaudio` instead of `pyaudio` in my solution. Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: I think `alsaaudio` is Linux only whereas `PyAudio` provides [`PortAudio`](http://www.portaudio.com/)-bindings and works on multiple platforms.

Comment: Hello @FrankZalkow, could you please have a look at my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53292811/convert-alsaaudio-to-pyaudio Thanks

Comment: Can you show how to parse two channels into a shaped numpy array?

Answer (score 22):

There is a library called `PyAudio`. You can use it to record in real-time. Plus with the help of `numpy.fromstring()` and `numpy.hstack()`, you can get the desired output. Please note that the following snippet is for `MONO-CHANNEL`.

```
import pyaudio
import numpy

RATE=16000
RECORD_SECONDS = 2.5
CHUNKSIZE = 1024

# initialize portaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=1, rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNKSIZE)

frames = [] # A python-list of chunks(numpy.ndarray)
for _ in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNKSIZE * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNKSIZE)
    frames.append(numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=numpy.int16))

#Convert the list of numpy-arrays into a 1D array (column-wise)
numpydata = numpy.hstack(frames)

# close stream
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

This is a tested code. It should work as charm. In order to check if your recorded data is correctly available in `numpydata`, you can add this following snippet after the previous code.

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
wav.write('out.wav',RATE,numpydata)
```

These lines will write your `numpydata` into "out.wav". Play the file to check the data.

PS: This is my first response in StackOverflow. Hope it helps.

Comment: Not bad for your first post :)

Comment: @deW1 Thanks for revising my answer and highlighting the terms. :)

Comment: @StitchesGuy90 I wish to plot the incoming audio data so that I get a  real time graph of the audio is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to the first answer here, but I have included missing part of plotting the Audio Data.

```
import pyaudio
import wave
import numpy as np
import noisereduce as nr

#This library helps us in plotting the  audio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

def plotAudio2(output):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=1, figsize=(20,4))
        plt.plot(output, color='blue')
        ax.set_xlim((0, len(output)))
        plt.show()

CHUNK = 22050
FORMAT = pyaudio.paFloat32
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 20

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []


for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    data_sample = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.float32)

    print("data sample")
    plotAudio2(data_sample)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

I have tested above code snippet, this worked for me perfectly fine.

**Note:** This code snippet was tested in Windows, and **matplotlib** might have some  issue in MacOS (I am not sure though)

Answer (score -1):

```
import librosa
file = 'audio/a1.wav'
signal, _ = librosa.load(file)
print(type(signal))
```