# Converting audio blob to wav

Tags: python, socket.io, blob, getusermedia

I am recording audio client side using `getUserMedia` and emitting it using socket `socket.emit('voice', blob );`on the receiving end in my flask server, I get the blob as a string. I can't find a solution to convert this string to a .wav file so I can pass it to my speech to text algorithm. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think this tutorial describes what you want: https://henri.io/posts/streaming-microphone-input-with-flask.html Also it would be nice to list the exact things you've tried so far rather than just saying that you can't find a solution. What about the `wave` module from the std-library (https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html), what about PyAudio (https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/) like described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24974032/reading-realtime-audio-data-into-numpy-array? Why don't these work for you?