# How to play music in left speaker and microphone voice in right speaker with raspberry pi python?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, microphone, stereotype

I have a USB mic and raspberry pi. Here is what I'm trying to do.

I have "music.wav" file where the sound track is set to left channel and I have USB mic connected to raspberry pi.

**When I play "music.wav" and speak in mic .I can hear music in left speaker and mic voice in both left and right speaker.**

I tried the below code and tried different ways,could not achieve the to restrict the voice to be in right speaker only.

Can someone help me how to restrict **music in only left speaker** and **voice in only right speaker** using python language?

Below code for voice from microphone coming in both speaker.
Need to restrict only in right speaker.Please help!!

```
import pyaudio
import os
import numpy as np

chunk=2800
RATE=44100

p=pyaudio.PyAudio()

#input stream setup
stream=p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,rate=RATE,channels=1, 
input_device_index = 1, input=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk)

#the code below is from the pyAudio library documentation referenced 
#below
#output stream setup
player=p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,rate=RATE,channels=1, 
output=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk)

while True:            #Used to continuously stream audio
   try:
       data=np.fromstring(stream.read(chunk,exception_on_overflow 
       =False),dtype=np.int16)
       player.write(data,chunk)
   except IOError:
       continue

#closes streams
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate
```

**UPDATE:**
After many tries,I executed the below code:Now voice is breaking not clear and I'm still getting in both speakers...I also changed the "player"--output channel to 2..No luck!!

```
import pyaudio
import os
import numpy as np

  
chunk=2800
RATE=44100

p=pyaudio.PyAudio()

#input stream setup
stream=p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,rate=RATE,channels=1, 
input_device_index = 1, input=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk)

player=p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,rate=RATE,channels=1, 
output=True, 
frames_per_buffer=chunk) #tried changing channels=2

while True:            #Used to continuously stream audio
   try:
      data=np.fromstring(stream.read(chunk,exception_on_overflow = 
      False),dtype=np.int16)    
      chunk_length = int(len(data)/2)           
      result = np.reshape(data, (chunk_length, 2),order='f')
      #result = np.reshape(data, (chunk_length, 2))  
      print(result)

      rightchannel=result[:, 1] #I need right
      #leftchannel=result[:, 0]
   
      print(rightchannel)
      player.write(rightchannel,chunk_length)
      #player.write(result,chunk)
  except IOError:
      continue
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
stream=p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,rate=RATE,channels=1, 
input_device_index = 1, input=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk)
player=p.open(format = pyaudio.paInt16,rate=RATE,channels=2, 
output=True, 
frames_per_buffer=chunk)

while True:            #Used to continuously stream audio
   try:
      data=np.fromstring(stream.read(chunk,exception_on_overflow = 
      False),dtype=np.int16)    
      chunk_length = int(len(data)/2)           
      result = np.reshape(data, (chunk_length, 2))     
      print(result)
      rightchannel=result[:, 1] #I need right
      #leftchannel=result[:, 0]      
      print(rightchannel)
      player.write(rightchannel,chunk)      
  except IOError:
      continue
 
  **ERROR**>>>>
  [[185 179]
  [183 175]
  [190 197]
  ..., 
  [156 156]
  [149 144]
  [145 146]]
  [179 175 197 ..., 156 144 146]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
  "/home/pi/RKR_MainAudioBase/Audio_GUI_RKR/MicFuncFiles/recorder.py", 
  line 25, in <module>
  player.write(rightchannel,chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 586, in write
  exception_on_underflow)
  ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous
```

Comment: I guess you’ll have to convert mono microphone input to right-only stereo (with every left channel sample set to zero) before sending it to audio output. Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636499/convert-multi-channel-pyaudio-into-numpy-array

Comment: Thanks for sharing,I tried it.. as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62862652/how-to-play-music-in-left-speaker-and-microphone-voice-in-right-speaker-with-ras/62971828#62971828      
 But getting below error Traceback                        
 (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/RKR_MainAudioBase/Audio_GUI_RKR/MicFuncFiles/recorder.py", line 25, 
in <module>
player.write(rightchannel,chunk)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 586, in write
exception_on_underflow)
ValueError: ndarray is not C-contiguous

Comment: Please update the code in your question with a [mre] that shows this error.

Comment: You have set player to be 2 channels?

Comment: @barny..yes i have tried and posted the method which you stated me to look into..Still not able to achieve. I was able to resolve that ndarray not C contagious error by adding order='f' while i reshape. however not able to resolve.

Comment: Not in a position to try this ATM - the player *must* be two channels

Comment: Thanks for the support....I changed the output channel to 2, if i make result = np.reshape(data, (chunk_length, 2),order='f'),the code executes with no error but voice data is breaking and appears in both speakers. So without order='f' I have posted code and error as "UPDATE 2" in the question. Not able to solve this C-contiguous error,your help is appreciated.

Comment: The chunk length doesn’t change - if it’s one second of mono microphone sound it must still play as one second of stereo sound - but as r and l are interleaved and you want the left channel to be silent you have to add the same number of zeroes alternately with the samples.

Comment: @barny thanks helped a lot.  Wonderful support..really appreciating.                                
It is working when you make input array channel as 1,Input data=[1 2 3 4 5 6] this mono which is from stream read for example,to make stereo just make output player  channel=2 and make data into dataout=[ 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6] this format which is [L0 R0 L1 R1...etc]. then player.write(dataout,chunk). And to have control over right channel make every 2nd,4th,6th etc position element as 0 and for left channel make 1st,3rd,5th element as 0. This is working perfectly well !!!!

Comment: Well done for getting it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution which I got after many research and findings:

It is working when you make input array channel as 1,Input data=[1 2 3 4 5 6] this mono which is from stream read for example,to make stereo just make output player channel=2 and make data into dataout=[ 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6] this format which is [L0 R0 L1 R1...etc]. then "player.write(dataout,chunk)".

And to have control over **right channel make every 2nd,4th,6th etc position element as 0 ex:dataout=[ 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6 0]** and for **left channel make 1st,3rd,5th element as 0. dataout=[ 0 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 6]**

This is working perfectly well !!!!